# State-of-art for sensor's anomaly detection

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, deep-learning, anomaly-detection

I am working on anomaly detection problem and I need your help and expertise. I have a sensor that records episodic time series data. For example, once in a while, the sensor activates for 10 seconds and records values at millisecond interval. My task is to identify whether the recorded pattern is not normal. In other words, I need to detect anomalies in that pattern compared to other recorded patterns.

What would be the state-of-the-art approaches to that?

Comment: A group like Computational Science seems more appropriate for your question. (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing my own research, the following methods proven to work very well in practice:

- [Variational Inference for On-line Anomaly Detection in
  High-Dimensional Time Series](http://dm.snu.ac.kr/static/docs/TR/SNUDM-TR-2015-03.pdf)
- [Multivariate Industrial Time Series
  with Cyber-Attack Simulation: Fault Detection Using an LSTM-based
  Predictive Data Model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.06676.pdf)